# Why doesn't moq setup all properties by default?

Tags: moq

I understand that in Moq, you need to set up properties before you can assign values. My question is *why* doesn't Moq just allow you to set properties by default without having to "set" them up.

Comment: You could turn it around and ask yourself: *why should an interface (or abstract base class) have properties in the first place?* Is it because you intend to implement those properties in more than one way? If so, how can Moq predict what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a question for the developer. Till then you can take a look at the [Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) and see if it helps answer your question.

`mock.SetupAllProperties();` which stubs all properties on a mock.

My guess would be that not all mocks would possess properties so making the framework attempt to look up and setup properties would not make for an efficient API. the opt-in option of setting it up if needed seems like an optimal approach.